# Example of a functor that creates limits but not strictly (other than equivalences)

Tags: category-theory, examples-counterexamples

In *Category Theory in Context*, Riehl defines creating limits as follows, for a functor $F: \mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{D}$ and diagram $D: I \to \mathbb{C}$:

> $F$ **creates** limits if whenever $FD: I \to \mathbb{D}$ has a limit in $\mathbb{D}$, there is some limit cone over $FD$ that can be lifted to a limit cone over $D$, and moreover $F$ reflects limits.

In other words, using terminology similar to [this answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/293199/425619), $F$ creates limits iff:

- it lifts limits up to isomorphism (in particular, it detects limits);
- it reflects limits.

Then the author says:

> With the exception of the equivalences the functors that one meets in practice that create certain limits and colimits tend to do so *strictly* in the sense of the following definition.
>
> Definition 3.3.7. A functor $F: \mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{D}$ **strictly creates** limits if for any diagram $D : I \to \mathbb{C}$ and any limit cone over $FD$,
>
> - there exists a unique lift of that cone to a cone over $D$, and
> - moreover, this lift defines a limit cone in $\mathbb{C}$.

As pointed out, I can think of an equivalence of categories that creates limits but not strictly, for example the equivalence $\mathrm{FinSet} \to \mathbb{N}$ onto its skeleton.
But I can't think of any other type of example.
**What is an example of a functor that creates limits but not strictly, other than an equivalence of categories?**